# Find other rows most closely associated with a column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to phrase this question.

I have a table with two columns: `tag` and `activity_id` used to track a many-to-many relationship between activities and tags. (In reality, tag is actually a numeric `tag_id`, but I'm simplifying this for the purposed of the question - I can figure out the JOIN later.)

Sample data:

```
tag, activity_id
"Ideation",52698
"Adult",52698
"Trans man",52698
"USA - Northwest",52698
"Transfeminine",52699
"Ideation",52699
"Adult",52702
"Trans man",52702
"USA - Northwest",52702
"Ideation",52702
"PTSD",52702
"Religious abuse / trauma",52702
"Adult",52709
"Ideation",52709
```

What I want to find is which tags appear most with others. For example, in the above Ideation and Adult appear with the same activity_id multiple times. Ideation and Trans Man also show up together. What I'd like is a query to show which tags are clustered together based on activity_id, ideally with some sort of rank based on how many times they appear together.

Thanks for any assistance - Please comment if I haven't explained this clearly enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a self-join and aggregation:

```
select s1.tag, s2.tag, count(*)
from sample s1 join
     sample s2
     on s1.activity_id = s2.activity_id and s1.tag < s2.tag
group by s1.tag, s2.tag
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. It's exactly what I needed. Here's the full query I used, with the JOIN I left out above to simplify the example:

`SELECT t1.tag, t2.tag, s1.tag_id, s2.tag_id, count(*)
FROM activities_tags s1
     JOIN activities_tags s2 ON s1.activity_id = s2.activity_id AND s1.tag_id < s2.tag_id
     JOIN tags t1 ON s1.tag_id = t1.id
     JOIN tags t2 ON s2.tag_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.tag, t2.tag, s1.tag_id, s2.tag_id
ORDER BY count(*) desc;`